# Java - Is it good practice to return interface or abstract types from methods?

Tags: java, interface, reference, abstract

I've got the following piece of code:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getWordCount(String text) {

    Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>();
    String[] wordsFromText = text.split("\\s+");

    for (String word : wordsFromText) {

        if (words.containsKey(word))
            words.put(word, words.get(word) + 1);
        else
            words.put(word, 1);
    }

    return words;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Integer> map = getWordCount("Ninjas are all over the place! We are all going to die!");

    // some logic that does something with the map...

}
```

I was wondering if it's okay, or if it's even good practice to return type Map instead of the concrete HashMap implementation type.

My second question is, why do people prefer to declare variables by having a reference of a more generic type pointing to an object of a concrete type(as in Map ref = new HashMap();), instead of just declaring a reference of the concrete object type that's pointing to an object of the same type? What are the pros/cons?

Comment: This question specifically targets *return* types. It is not an duplicate as the issue of programming to interfaces/programming to implementation does not directly answer how to decide the nature of the type to return

Comment: @MichaelWiles hopefully the new dupe is more appropriate.

Comment: Oh, just saw the new dupe, thanks a bunch!

Comment: P.S. What does dupe really mean? :D